# Create Docker container with predefined Redis dump

Tags: docker, redis

I try to create Redis docker container with data. My approach is inspired by this question. But it doesn't work by some reason.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis

EXPOSE 6379

COPY redis-dump.csv /

RUN nohup bash -c "redis-server --appendonly yes" & sleep 5s \
    && cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe \
    && redis-cli shutdown save
    && ls /data
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  redisdata:

services:
  redis:
    build:
      context: docker/redis
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

When I created container, Redis is empty. When I connect to container directory `/data` is empty as well. But when I see logs when docker has been creating there is `dump.rdb` and `appendonly.aof` files. Dump file is in container. And when I run `cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe` in container then data is available in Redis. So, the question is why db files are absent?

Here is a full logs of creating a container:

```
Creating network "restapi_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "restapi_redisdata" with default driver
Building redis
Step 1/4 : FROM redis
 ---> a55fbf438dfd
Step 2/4 : EXPOSE 6379
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2e6e5609b5b3
Step 3/4 : COPY redis-dump.csv /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39330e43e72a
Step 4/4 : RUN nohup bash -c "redis-server --appendonly yes" & sleep 5s     && cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe     && redis-cli shutdown save     && ls /data
 ---> Running in 7e290e6a46ce
7:C 10 May 2019 19:45:32.509 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
7:C 10 May 2019 19:45:32.509 # Redis version=5.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7, just started
7:C 10 May 2019 19:45:32.509 # Configuration loaded
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.510 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.510 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.510 # Server initialized
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.510 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.510 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:32.511 * Ready to accept connections
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 67600
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:37.750 # User requested shutdown...
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:37.750 * Calling fsync() on the AOF file.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:37.920 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:37.987 * DB saved on disk
7:M 10 May 2019 19:45:37.987 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
appendonly.aof
dump.rdb
Removing intermediate container 7e290e6a46ce
 ---> 1f1cd024e68f

Successfully built 1f1cd024e68f
Successfully tagged restapi_redis:latest
Creating restapi_redis_1 ... done
```

Here is sample of data:

```
SET user:id:35 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:66 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:28 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:40 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:17 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:63 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:67 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:45 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:23 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:79 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:26 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:94 85.214.132.117
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the volume before starting your container:

```
docker volume rm redisdata
```

Then change your Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM redis

EXPOSE 6379

COPY redis-dump.csv /

ENTRYPOINT nohup bash -c "redis-server --appendonly yes" & sleep 5s \
    && cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe \
    && redis-cli save \
    && redis-cli shutdown \
    && ls /data
```

For a quicker result I suggest to map the volume to a local folder:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./redisdata:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

After you see that it runs you can switch back to the normal docker volumes.

Now run:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

The container will start and will also gracefully stop because there is no process left running. But the data will be present in the data folder.

Generally when working with databases the population should be done on a running container instead of an image.

After discussions we decided to use a multi-stage build:

```
FROM redis as import 

EXPOSE 6379 

COPY redis-dump.csv / 

RUN mkdir /mydata 

RUN nohup bash -c "redis-server --appendonly yes" & sleep 5s \ 
&& cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe \ 
&& redis-cli save \ 
&& redis-cli shutdown \ 
&& cp /data/* /mydata/ 

RUN ls /mydata 

FROM redis 

COPY --from=import /mydata /data 
COPY --from=import /mydata /mydata 

RUN ls /data 

CMD ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
```

The first stage (import) is almost the same as the original posted. Since we noticed that after the last RUN command the files in /data are removed, we make a copy in a different folder called /mydata.

The second stage uses the same image as base but it only copies from the previous stage what it needs: the data from /mydata. It places this data in the /data folder and then starts the redis server.

Comment: I remove all things not only volumes: docker-compose down -v --rmi local, it didn't help.

Comment: Can you post the output of 'docker volume ls'?

Comment: Also you can remove the volume mapping, run the container and then execute a shell in the container and check the contents of /data directly inside the running container.

Comment: docker volume ls | grep redis shows nothing, there is no volume for redis. I tried already connect to container and check /data dir, it's empty by some reason, it's actually my question.

Comment: But then it is not a docker or volumes issue like I read it. It must be the way you start it. If you share a few lines from the CSV file that I could work with I can start it on my own and give you the answer

Comment: Here is sample of data:
SET user:id:35 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:66 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:28 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:40 85.214.132.117
SET user:id:17 85.214.132.117

Comment: But I am not sure it's data issue, because if I'll roll out data manually `cat /redis-dump.csv | redis-cli --pipe` then it works and I can see data in Redis

Comment: I attached sample of data to question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193179/discussion-between-mihai-and-slesh).

Comment: @slesh I updated the solution. I works for me and I can see the 2 files that your initial "ls /data" showed. let me know